# What's the best solution for my laravel project to send "forgotten password" emails?

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, email, namecheap

I'm in the middle of deploying my project, and the last part is getting the "forgotten password" system to work. Currently, without any mail configuration, I get the error

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "
```

I have bought my domain through namecheap.com and hosting on digitalocean.com.

My .env mail config currently looks like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

, which obviously isn't supposed to work.

Where do I go to get a mail username and password? Thanks.

Comment: You need to either set up local SMTP and use that, or engage one of Laravel's supported third-party mail providers (Amazon SES, Mailgun, Postmark, etc.).

Comment: According to digitalocean it's a lot of work to maintain an email server, but I'm very inexperienced when it comes to email stuff. Since I'm already paying namecheap and digitalocean I'd rather not include another party. DO does have a suggestion for postfix, is that something you'd recommend?

Comment: Quite a few of the supported providers (SendGrid, SES, probably others) have a generous free tier. For small volumes, you may also be able to push it through something like Gmail. I would not personally, under any circumstances, run my own SMTP server, especially if I were "very inexperienced".

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize some of those had free tiers. I went with mailgun. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with mailgun's free option for now. It seems to work fine so far!